# Returning Substring of Indeterminate Length

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to pull a substring from formatted text messages using python in order to return a datetime to then insert into a SQL database. I am having issues returning just the date since I don't want any of the string after it or before it during this function call.

Here is a sample line of the text file (with identifying info removed):

```
<sms protocol="0" address="+##########" date="1557093540527" type="1" subject="null" body="Don't text and drive! &#129315;" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+##########" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1557093540000" sub_id="2" readable_date="May 5, 2019 5:59:00 PM" contact_name="XXXX" />
```

I am trying to access the bit after readable_date=". The contact name in this case is not relevant so I could theoretically toss out the entire end and then partition after readable_date=" but this is fairly large amount of texts (4000-5000 messages) and if feels like there has to be a better way, but I have been searching for a few hours and haven't had luck finding one.

Comment: Looks like XML, so I would start by throwing it in an xml parser, There's several to choose from built into python. Then I would use the dateutil parser.parse to parse the string into a python datetime object, then you can put it in a database very easuly at that point

Comment: Please show a [mcve] illustrating what you tried.